# Rails polymorphic relationship not propagating implicitly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capybara, rails-activerecord

I've got the following two classes

```
 class Car < Vehicle
   has_one :steering_wheel, as: :attached
 end

 class SteeringWheel < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :attached

   has_many :components
   has_one :rim, class_name: 'Components', order: 'id DESC'
   attr_accessible :components
 end

 class Component < ActiveRecord::Base
    include SpecificationFileService::Client

    attr_accessible :created_by
    belongs_to :steering_wheel 
 end
```

Then in my specs:

```
context "given an attachment", :js do
  before do
    @car = create(:car, make: "honda")
    @steering_wheel = SteeringWheel.create(attached: @car)
    @steering_wheel.save
    @car.save
    @car.reload
  end
  specify "test the setup", :js do
    puts @car.steering_wheel
  end
end
```

Which prints: `nil`

A way that I have found fixes this is explicitly setting steering_wheel on car like so:

```
 @car.steering_wheel = @steering_wheel
```

just before the `save`.

EDIT:

As suggested in the comments below, I have tried adding polymorphic: true, which did not resolve the issue. Also, I've fleshed out more of the SteeringWheel model above

My question is why, and how can I add this to the callback chain implicitly

Comment: do you have validations on your `SteeringWheel` model ? i suspect that `@steering_wheel` never gets saved but fails silently (neither `create` or `save` raise an error on failure, and `create` does return a record). try to use the bang versions `create!` and `save!` to see if something's going wrong here.

Comment: Agree with m_x, I make it a principle to always use `create!` and `save!` in tests. If your test assumes the data exists, the test should fail without it. Imagine if you had a bug in your code that made the test pass without the data...

Comment: Doesn't it has to be `belongs_to :attached, polymorphic: true`?

Comment: I've tried polymorphic: true. Also, I've fleshed out the steeringWheel Model in the question above....

Answer (score 1):

Like @abraham-p mentioned in a comment, you need to declare the `belongs_to` relation as:

```
belongs_to :attached, polymorphic: true
```

Otherwise it will attempt to look for an `Attached` model, and be sure to include these fields in your `SteeringWheel` model:

```
attached_type
attached_id
```

The rest is worked out by Rails :)